# how to get attribute all dropdown values selected by the product in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, dropdown-attribute

I am trying to show the attribute's dropdown values selected in product. For that I am using this way.

```
<?php $parentIds = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($_product->getId());

if(count($parentIds)>0 && $_product->getTypeId() == "simple")
    {
        /*?><script>console.log('<?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>')</script><?php */
    }
else { 
        foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) :
            $_p = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());
            $productList[] = $_p;
            $priceRuleCats = $_p->getprice_rule_category();

            if(!empty($priceRuleCats)){
                $priceRuleList = array_unique(array_merge($priceRuleList,explode(',',$priceRuleCats)));
            }
        endforeach;    
    // save the full list 
    $fullList = $productList;

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    $price_rules = $objectManager->get('Startupready\PriceRules\Model\Quantitybreaks');
    $price_rules->load($priceRuleList);
    $price_rules->getPricingTables();

    $current_table = 0;
    $size_options = array();
    $price_breaks = array();

    // use first product from loop to see what the size options are & load price breaks for those options
    $firstProduct = array_shift($productList);

    // this product's price rule category
    $price_rule_category = $firstProduct->getprice_rule_category();

    // loop through simple products
    $conf = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable')->setProduct($firstProduct);
    $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
    foreach($simple_collection as $simple){
        echo $simple->getsize_option();
        //also i tried like this
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($simple['size_option']); echo "</pre>";
    }
?>
```

but when I am putting my code inside the list.phtml file, no any products are displaying on this page.

Meanwhile I am just trying to get that product attribute inside this array so that if a product have assigned this values (doropdown values) then I'll show those values in frontend. Kindly please help me to do this. Thank in advance.

Comment: I think the bug is "setProduct()" function which i am using to assign my "$firstproduct". Because i search this function inside "Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable" path. but there is no any kind of function like this. And when i tried to create this function in my custom created module, and then connect my custom module. same thing my product not displaying on list page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I should start by saying that it is **NOT** recommended practice to directly instantiate the Object Manager. You can read more about that [here](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/dependency-injection-magento-2/). Although, it is not preventing your code from working.

Second, this logic does not belong in a template phtml file. You should be creating your own module, a small one, that runs through the logic and lets it echo out onto the page via a method call within your phtml file. Also, if you had a module, you could implement the necessary dependency injection to retrieve your data.

Thirdly, inside of the `$_productCollection` loop, you are calling `$_p->load($_product->getId())`. This is not only unnecessary but super inefficient.

Let it be known that the code sample below is enough to obtain the info you want to display, but by no means would I recommend implementing your custom code in this manner. So, once you get the data you seek, please see [Alan Storm's Magento 2 Tutorial Series](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/) and patiently go through them from beginning to end. This will help you gain a better understanding as to how certain crucial elements on Magento 2 work.

---

Here is the quick and dirty way to get the data requested in your original question:

Find the line in the list.phtml file that looks like this `<?php foreach($_productCollection as $_product): ?>`. This is not the loop you created, but the loop that was already in the file before you edited it.

Completely replace this line:

```
<?php foreach($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
```

With this:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\ConfigurableFactory $configurableFactory */
$configurableFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\ConfigurableFactory');
?>

<?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
<?php foreach($_productCollection as $_product): ?>

    <?php
    if($_product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
        /** @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurable */
        $configurable = $configurableFactory->create();

        // 3 options to get attributes, but i am using
        # $attributes = $configurable->getConfigurableAttributes($_product);
        # $attributes = $configurable->getConfigurableAttributeCollection($_product);

        $attributes = $configurable->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);
        foreach($attributes as $attrId => $attribute){
            echo '<pre>',print_r($attribute),'</pre>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

This will expose all of the available data for each product and then you can do whatever you need to.

Comment: don't know why but when i am trying like this , my products are not showing on the list page...:(

Comment: Something else must be wrong. Can you post the entire page of code? Also will check in the morning as I must sleep now. I did test my code before posting and it works so the key is to figure out what the remaining problem is.

Comment: you didnt post your file

Comment: I edited my question. please check it.

Comment: looking now. What does `$_p->getprice_rule_category()` refer to? Is `price_rule_category` an attribute code?

Comment: For any attribute code, you dont include the underscore, you instead remove underscores and capitalize the first letter in each segment. So, `$_p->getprice_rule_category()` should be `$_p->getPriceRuleCategory()` and magento will translate that into `$_p->getData('price_rule_category')`

Comment: yes friend. this is an attribute code to get the category rule of the products which is loaded on the page.

Comment: Ok, please see my comment just after. in the meantime, im looking through the code now

Comment: Btw, is this code going into your own custom class or are you putting it right in the template file?

Comment: Yes dude. I changed `$_p->getprice_rule_category()` into `$_p->getPriceRuleCategory()`. And i'm putting this code inside list.phtml file.

Comment: ok, and `$simple->getsize_option();` should be `$simple->getSizeOption();`. Each time you want to get data like this there are two ways to do it, `$simple->getSizeOption();` or `$simple->getData('size_option');`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. and i hope you'll resolve this error very smartly. Cheers friend.....:)

Comment: doing my best :-)

Comment: Dear friend. I can try `$simple->getSizeOption();` only after get the value inside `$simple_collection` array. But thanks for remind me...:)

Comment: I tried ` $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('size_option');
            if ($attribute){
                echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
            } ` and after putting this instead ` $conf = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable')->setProduct($firstProduct);
    $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions(); ` . I am getting " NO " in my frondend and all products are showing. But not understanding what it is...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47051/discussion-between-shawn-abramson-and-yudi).